# Addressing the tab menu in view when using taxonomy

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-panels

I use taxonomy terms to address my menus(these taxonomy terms show the structure of my site) so when I create a view I should use the taxonomy path (instead of alias) for the page setting (the only way that I can link the view to my taxonomy address path as far as I know :P ). whenever I see the page URL I can see the alias. now I'm trying to set up a page that has 2 tabs. I have set it up but the problem is when I click in the tab I see the taxonomy path instead of alias ? (for example taxonomy/term/6/digital instead of CCTV/digital However default menu tab still work correctly and show the alias CCTV)
Is there any way to show the alias instead of taxonomy term address ?

Comment: Is this a problem for all your content or only on this page where you have these tabs?

Comment: No this Problem is just for the tabs that I have created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a view that is filtering your taxonomy terms. If you render the results as fields, each field can have it's formatter. If you need a custom form of the output, you can define your own formatter or generate one via GUI with help of: [custom formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters).
In case that you render your output as rendered entity, you need to find the right template file and use the drupal_get_path_alias() function within it.

As last I would hint you a great module that also might help you: [taxonomy menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)

Comment: Thanks Francis for your response but my problem is different than you responded. the context work for correctly and I'm just facing with a not desire url text in my site. I was looking for a solution that fix the problem without changing the structure of site. TNX

Comment: Could you please explain "and I'm just facing with a not desire url text in my site."? Is your site online?

Comment: I just Set it up Locally, and instead of URL Alias for the added tabs the address of taxonomy term shows in the URL.